# Cannot access js function from html button

Tags: javascript, parcel

I'm using parcel as a bundler. I trying to call js function from button click but it is producing an error.

```html
<button onclick="test()">Click</button>
<script src="./js/index.js"></script>
```

```js
// index.js file

function test() {
  console.log("test");
}
```

I'm getting this error
(index):19 Uncaught ReferenceError: test is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):19)

Comment: Define the js before the button - or better, add a load event handler that adds the eventListener. Also look in the network tab to see if the file has loaded at all

Comment: @mplungjan not required , doesn't get evaluated until event occurs

Comment: Hmm, In any case If you click before the js file is loaded or the file gives 404 you do have an issue

Comment: The rest of the functions are executing which is inside then index.js

Comment: Then you are likely shadowing the test by having something else called test

Comment: bundler is likely wrapping the code in an IIFE and the function is not in global window scope which is required for `onclick`

Comment: @mplungjan I tried different function name but same error.

Comment: @charlietfl I think you are right that's why it is not working

Answer (score 1):

If you have your function inside a load event handler it will fail

Also if you define it with

`let test = ....` it is only known in the scope it is defined

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  
  var test1 = function() { // this will not be known to the button's inline handler
    console.log(test.value)
  }

})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" />
<button class="test" onclick="test1()">Click</button>
```

Also if you rename the function below to test, it will fail with undefined because it is shadowed by one of the IDs or names in the page

```js
function test1() {
  console.log(test.value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="test" id="test" />
<button class="test" onclick="test1()">Click</button>
```

Solution:

```js
function test() {
  alert("Yes")
}
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
   document.getElementById("but").addEventListener("click",test);
})
```

```html
<button id="but">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If instead of doing

```
function test() {
  console.log("test");
}
```

you do

```
test = function() {
  console.log("test");
}
```

or

```
test = () => {
  console.log("test");
}
```

it works. I guess declaring functions as global variables makes them visible in inline HTML calls scope